# Feeding multiline input (here documents) to commands in cmd.exe scripts

Tags: cmd.exe, shell-script, stdin

In Bash, I can do something like this

```
somecmd << END
a lot of 
text here
END
```

to feed input to a command directly from a script. I need to do the same in CMD.exe batch files (.cmd scripts). Is it possible?

Comment: Now that I know what they are called, I found a previous question on Stackoverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1015163/heredoc-for-windows-batch Too complex for me. Time to switch to another shell/language :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe you can use a single `^` character for each line.

EG:

```
echo This is a really long ^
text message that spans multiple ^
lines
```

returns:

```
C:\Users\Jonno>echo This is a really long ^
More? text message that spans multiple ^
More? lines
This is a really long text message that spans multiple lines
```

Comment: Thanks! While useful, I would need to provide input via stdin, not as command line arguments. I could pipe the `echo` command, but then I lose the linebreaks. I also believe there is a limitation on the length of the command line.

Comment: @Krumelur Ah, I understand now, sorry, I misinterpreted the question. I'm not sure if you saw the previous comment linking to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6979747/read-stdin-stream-in-a-batch-file) and how relevant it would be to your situation?

Comment: Yes, I saw it and it is not really relevant for me. This question on SO is however exactly what I ask for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1015163/heredoc-for-windows-batch . Alas, it seems impossible to do in a simple way.

Comment: I am marking your question as an answer since it is apparently the closest you can get in cmd.exe without some serious hacking or external dependencies.

Answer (score 6):

It's simple, but not as clean looking as it is in Unix/Linux.  Try this:

```
(@echo.a lot of
@echo.text here
) | somecmd
```

Note that the `.` after the echo statement allows you to begin a line with blanks.  The `@` symbol is needed to prevent the echo statement from being sent to `somecmd`.  You can eliminate the `@` symbol thusly:

```
echo off
(echo.a lot of
echo.text here
) | somecmd
echo on
```

Comment: worked on Windows 10 CMD, but does not work on PowerShell FWIW. Used with DiskPart to pipe some startup command (without making a single line text file to use as script).

Comment: Yes, these are statements that work with cmd.exe, not with powershell.exe.  If you want to write scrips for PowerShell, this is not the topic for you.

Comment: Here's another example...

Comment: Suppose you have a program named ABCDEFG.exe, which requires multi-line input from STDIN...  otherwise known as "control cards".  This is a very common scenario in Unix, Linux, and many "mainframe" operating systems such as Hewlett Packard's MPE and IBM's z/OS.

Suppose the program requires three lines of input, and the ABCDEFG.exe program is located in "C:\My Directory" (note the space in My Directory)...

Here's how that works in cmd.exe:
    echo off
    (echo.CONTROL CARD ONE
    echo.CONTROL CARD TWO
    echo.CONTROL CARD THREE
    ) | "C:\My Directory\ABCDEFG.exe"
    echo on

Answer (score 0):

Until now, I don't have found any solution to this problem !

I have only a **workaround** in defining some BAT scripts.

Using my script, the solution to your problem look like this

```
call INIT-TRAMEX.bat

%assign-sysout% FILE.SYSOUT.TXT

%w% a lot of 
%w% text here

somecmd <%sysout%
```

But in all cases, the direct indirection is impossible.

`INIT-TRAMEX.bat` file defines `%ASSIGN-SYSOUT%` and `%W%` variables

```
::******************************************************************************
::* INIT-TRAMEX.bat
::******************************************************************************

@echo OFF

set scriptdir=c:\Scripts

set ASSIGN-SYSOUT=call %scriptdir%\AssignSysout.bat

set WRITE-TEXT=call %scriptdir%\WriteText.bat
set W=call %scriptdir%\WriteText.bat
```

`ASSIGN-SYSOUT` script defines `%sysout%` variable and create an empty file.
It contains following lines

```
set sysout=%1
@echo.>%sysout%
del %sysout%
```

`WRITE-TEXT` script contains following lines

```
IF "%1"=="" goto line
echo %* >>%sysout%
goto quit

:line

echo. >>%sysout%

:quit
```

Using this tips, DOS script is more readable.